# How to nest enums in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

Let's say I have a function like this but with many more possible values for the enum parameter:

```
enum API{
    userDetails = "/api/user/details",
    userPosts = "/api/user/posts",
    userComments = "/api/user/comments",
    postDetails = "/api/post/details",
    postComments = "/api/post/comments"
    //...
};

function callAPI(endpoint: API/*, some more params*/){
    // some code to deal with the specified endpoint...
}

callAPI(API.userComments);
```

The above code works fine, but I need to group the many values of the enum into an organized hierarchical structure in order to make things a little more organized... For example, it would be much better if the syntax for calling the API can be `callAPI(API.user.comments)` instead of `callAPI(API.userComments)`.

I tried things like the below attempts but it looks like none were accepted as a valid syntax for typescript.

Attempt 1

```
enum API{
    user = {
        details : "/api/user/details",
        userPorts : "/api/user/posts",
        userComments : "/api/user/comments"
    }
    post = {
        postDetails : "/api/post/details",
        postComments : "/api/post/comments"
    }
}
```

Attempt 2

```
enum user {
    details = "/api/user/details",
    userPorts = "/api/user/posts",
    userComments = "/api/user/comments"
}
enum post {
    postDetails = "/api/post/details",
    postComments = "/api/post/comments"
}
enum API{
    user,
    post
}
```

Attempt 3

```
enum user {
    details = "/api/user/details",
    userPorts = "/api/user/posts",
    userComments = "/api/user/comments"
}
enum post {
    postDetails = "/api/post/details",
    postComments = "/api/post/comments"
}
enum API{
    user = user,
    post = post
}
```

Attempt 4

```
enum user {
    details = "/api/user/details",
    userPorts = "/api/user/posts",
    userComments = "/api/user/comments"
}
enum post {
    postDetails = "/api/post/details",
    postComments = "/api/post/comments"
}
enum API{
    user:user
    post:post
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could wrap it inside a [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html):

```js
namespace API{
    export enum User {
        details = "/api/user/details",
        posts = "/api/user/posts",
        comments = "/api/user/comments",
    }
    export enum Post {
        details = "/api/post/details",
        comments = "/api/post/comments",
    }
}

console.log(API.User.comments)
console.log(API.Post.details)
```

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that it's not possible with enums - right hand side of an enum member can be either nothing, number, string, or another enum value.
See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html for more details.

But you can easily achieve what you want with plain objects.

```js
const API = {
  user: {
    details: "/api/user/details",
    posts: "/api/user/posts",
  },
  // ...
};
```

If you're worried that it might be modified, you can use [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

If you need to pass the whole API object to a function via argument then you'll need to define an interface for it too, but otherwise autocomplete and checks should work just fine.

-------- edit

Adding types in case you find them useful:

```js
export type ApiRoutes<TRoute extends string> = { [key in TRoute]: string };

export interface MyApi {
  user: ApiRoutes<"details" | "posts" | "comments">;
  post: ApiRoutes<"details" | "comments">;
}
```

Comment: You can also add `as const` at the end of the object to make it only readable. This won't prevent runtime modification, but the type should prevent compilation of attempts to modify it

Comment: I think I'm going to use this. Even though I would've preferred if I could have API as a type in order to implement type validation.

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but you could use these types: As suggested before, use `as const` after the object initialization. Then to get your type, first make a general use case `type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];` which gives you a union of object values. And then `type APIRoute = ValueOf<ValueOf<typeof API>>` which gives you the values of the values, which are the string routes. This should work as long as the depth stays the same, idk how to do it for a dynamic depth